# Why is -dontusemixedcaseclassnames included in the default ProGuard-android.xml file?

Tags: android, proguard

According to the documentation -dontusemixedcaseclassnames turns off the feature that causes files to self distruct if extracted on windows. surely this is a good thing when trying to hide your code. Why is it enabled, is there a downside to not using it?

> **-dontusemixedcaseclassnames**
>
> Specifies not to generate mixed-case class names while obfuscating. By
>   default, obfuscated class names can contain a mix of upper-case
>   characters and lower-case characters. This creates perfectly
>   acceptable and usable jars. Only if a jar is unpacked on a platform
>   with a case-insensitive filing system (say, Windows), the unpacking
>   tool may let similarly named class files overwrite each other. Code
>   that self-destructs when it's unpacked! Developers who really want to
>   unpack their jars on Windows can use this option to switch off this
>   behavior. Obfuscated jars will become slightly larger as a result.
>   Only applicable when obfuscating.

Answer (score 2):

Dalvik bytecode works fine with similar mixed-case class names. I suspect the configuration in the Android SDK contains the option to avoid confusion for developers who inspect their own compiled code.